# How do I get number delivered from the _Job Data View?

Tags: marketing-cloud, jobs

I'm trying to automate my monthly reporting and I have some queries that pull total opens, clicks etc and then figures out unique opens, clicks. I'm trying to pull total delivered for a job and total sent, but I don't see that as an option in the Data View. Is there another way to get this information?

https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/automation_studio/using_automation_studio_activities/using_the_query_activity/data_views/data_view_job/

Comment: COUNT * in Jobs should give you number sent, on another table Count * in the bounces table, and subtract the difference for Number Delivered?

Comment: Yes I suppose. Is that how number delivered is calculated? I can give that a try and see if it matches up with the send data.

Comment: Not a 100% sure of how its calculating and I would definitely validate it with send counts over taking advice off some guy on Stack Exchange :)

Comment: @Data_Kid I don't think that's it because counting all rows in _Jobs just gives me the number of jobs delivered, but not total each job was sent to right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the assumption that every email not delivery is reccorded on the bounced data view, Try this to get the totals.

```
SELECT

s.JobID
,TotalSends
,TotalBounces
,(TotalSends - TotalBounces) AS TotalDelivered

FROM


(SELECT 

JobID   
,MAX(row) as TotalSends

FROM 

(SELECT 

JobID
,row_number()over(partition by JobID order by SubscriberKey ASC) as row 

FROM _Sent 
) f

GROUP BY f.JobID) s 

INNER JOIN (SELECT 

JobID   
,MAX(row) as TotalBounces

FROM 

(SELECT 

JobID
,row_number()over(partition by JobID order by SubscriberKey ASC) as row 

FROM _Bounce ) d

GROUP BY d.JobID) b 

ON s.JobID = b.JobID
```

The you can subtract the totals to arrive at number delivered.

Comment: What about the exclusion (if there are any)? How to consider exclusions in the sql script? OR it is correct to say that exclusion won't exist in SENT data view so we do not need to do anything for exclusion in the query? and total - bounce should give an accurate count?